# Jquery calls not working in $viewContentLoaded of Angular

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs

Unable to call jquery functions in $viewContentLoaded event of Angular controller, here is the code for the same.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    jQuery.growlUI('Growl Notification', 'Saved Succesfully');
    jQuery('#category').tree()
    });
```

Is any configuration required here?? I tried even noConflict(); var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
Does it require any other configuration?

Thanks,
Abdul

Comment: Could you make a punker showing the problem? http://plnkr.co/edit, press New -> AngularJS

Comment: @AndyJoslin Thanks for the reply Andy. After looking at your code yesterday, have moved all this to custom directive. However, i have new problem now, am using 'ng-repeat' in my custom directive.
However, i need to call a jquery function on the custom directive element after the content is loaded.

In postlink function, template is getting loaded but 'ng-repeat' elements are yet to get executed.
Is there any other function/ event where i need to call the jQuery function. (function which i would call normally in $document.ready() ).

Comment: You should $watch the list that is being repeated, and each time it changes re-apply the jQuery function.

Comment: @AndyJoslin Thanks for the response Andy. Could learn Angular in short time due to continuos support of Angular community.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First thing first, don't do DOM manipulation from controller. Instead do it from directives.

You can do same thing in directive link method. You can access the `element` on which directive is applied.

Make sure you load jquery before angularjs scripts, then grawlUI, three, angularJS and finally your application script. Below is directive sample

```
var app = angular.module("someModule", []);

app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        $.growlUI('Growl Notification', 'Saved Succesfully');
        element.tree();
    };

});
```

angularjs has built in jQuery lite. 
if you load full jquery after angular, since jQuery is already defined, the full jquery script will skip execution.

==Update after your comment==

I reviewed again your question after comment and realised that content which is loaded trough ajax is appended to some div in your angular view. Then you want to apply element.tree() jquery plugin to that content. Unfortunately example above will not work since it is fired on linking which happened before your content from ajax response is appended to element with directive I showed to you. But don't worry, there is a way :) tho it is quick and dirty but it is just for demo.

Let's say this is your controller

```
function ContentCtrl($scope, $http){
  $scope.trees=[];

  $scope.submitSomethingToServer=function(something){
     $http.post("/article/1.html", something)
          .success(function(response,status){
               // don't forget to set correct order of jquery, angular javascript lib load
               $.growlUI('Growl Notification', 'Saved Succesfully');

               $scope.trees.push(response); // append response, I hope it is HTML
     });
  }

}
```

Now, directive which is in controller scope (it uses same scope as controller)

```
var app = angular.module("someModule", []);

app.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch("trees", function(){
            var newParagraph=$("<p>" + scope.trees[scope.trees.length-1] + "</p>" ); // I hope this is ul>li>ul>li...or what ever you want to make as tree
            element.append(newParagraph); 
            newParagraph.tree(); //it will apply tree plugin after content is appended to DOM in view
        }); 
    };

});
```

The second approach would be to $broadcast or $emit event from controller (depends where directive is, out or in scope of controller) after your ajax completes and you get content from server. Then directive should be subscribed to this event and handle it by receiving passed data (data=content as string) and do the rest as I showed you above.

The thing is, threat that content from ajax as data all the way it comes to directive, then inject it to element in which you want to render it and apply tree plugin to that content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Milan. I have changed this code to directive. I have put the code inside the template and configured the same in templateUrl option. However, i had to use ng-repeat in the template and i need to call above jquery functions after whole page is rendered.i.e.likedocument.ready(). Whereas in link function of directive, ng-repeat tag one has not yet loaded. So, my jQuery calls are not making any difference. Any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Comment: I think I finally know what your app is doing, check update in my answer

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Milan. This gave me complete solution to my problem.Learnt many things that i can do using Angular through this.