# Fire an event immediately after $scope.$digest

Tags: angularjs, events, hash, scope

In my AngularJS app, there's several points at which I want to wait for a `$scope` to be processed into the DOM, and then run some code on it, like a jQuery `fadeIn`, for example.

Is there a way to listen for a "digestComplete" message of some sort?

My current method is: immediately after setting whatever `$scope` variables I want rendered, use `setTimeout` with a delay of 0 ms, so that it will let the scope finish digesting, and then run the code, which works perfectly. Only problem is, I very occasionally see the DOM render before that setTimeout returns. I'd like a method that is guaranteed to fire after digest, and before render.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this [jQuery fade-in-and-out fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzachtli/K4Kx8/1/) (which I found it on the [JSFiddles Examples](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/JsFiddle-Examples) wiki page), the author defines a "fadey" directive and performs the jQuery fadeIn (or fadeOut) in the directive's *link* function"

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" fadey="500">
...
myApp.directive('fadey', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        var duration = parseInt(attrs.fadey);
        if (isNaN(duration)) {
            duration = 500;
        }
        elm = jQuery(elm); // this line is not needed if jQuery is loaded before Angular
        elm.hide();
        elm.fadeIn(duration)
```

Another possible solution is to use [$evalAsync](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync):  see [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/734#issuecomment-3657272) by Miško, in which he states:

> The asyncEval is after the DOM construction but before the browser renders.
>   I believe that is the time you want to attach the jquery plugins. otherwise
>   you will have flicker. if you really want to do after the browser render
>   you can do $defer(fn, 0);

($defer was renamed $timeout).

However, I think using a directive (since you are manipulating the DOM) is the better approach.

Here's a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021152/jquery-calls-not-working-in-viewcontentloaded-of-angular) where the OP tried listening for $viewContentLoaded events on the scope (which is yet another alternative), in order to apply some jQuery functions.  The suggestion/answer was again to use a directive.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, this example will work the same way as an AngularJS built-in **ng-show** directive, except it will **fade-in** or **fade-out** based on AngularJS condition:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-ds-fade="{condition}">
<!-- E.g.: ng-ds-fade="items.length > 0" -->
...
myApp.directive('ngDsFade', function () {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.css('display', 'none');
    scope.$watch(attrs.ngDsFade, function(value) {
      if (value) {
        element.fadeIn(200);
      } else {
        element.fadeOut(100);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Source:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464939/Angular-JS-Using-Directives-to-Create-Custom-Attri

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to run some jQuery stuff why not try the Angular-UI jQuery Passthrough?