# How to know if angular is done booting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to do some stuff outside angular, but only after it's fully booted, is there some kind of event or something similar I can bind to?

Comment: See similar questions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838205/call-angular-function-on-document-ready

Comment: [$asyncEval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) might help. ["The asyncEval is after the DOM construction but before the browser renders."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12113148/597419)

Answer (score 1):

You could just execute a function in the .run function for angular:

```
app.run(function(){
   //some function outside of angular
   myFunctionThatDoesOtherStuff();
});
```